# How to query a view in cloudant using startkey and endkey where key has two elements in it?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, nosql

I have a requirement to filter some records on the basis of period for example get me all products count between 201704 and 201705.

So my emit is something like:

```
emit([doc.productId, doc.period],1)
```

and reduce used is `_count`. But when i am trying to filter on startkey and endkey it gives me all records. I am trying something like:

```
startkey=["201604"]&endkey=[{},"201605"]
```

where my key structure is something like key:

```
[
"aws-60826348802",
201703
]
```

**I dont want to reverse the order of elements in key** as i want a count on ids by defining the `group_level=1`. Could anyone help me out. I did not get any solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to select (with startkey/endkey), your index needs to be in *in that order*. Let's say your docs look like this:

```
{
  "_id": "someid",
  "product": "aws-60826348802",
  "date": "201604",
  "price": 42.42
}
```

You could create a map function to index the documents in date order like so:

```
function(doc) {
  emit([doc.date, doc.product], doc.price);
}
```

You now have a two-dimensional key (on date & product code) and the value is emitted is the price.

This allows you to select items by date:

```
?startkey=["201604"]  // find items where the date is >= 201604
?startkey=["201604"]&endkey=["201605"]  // find items in April 2016
```

if you choose a reducer (_count, _sum, or _stats) you can also perform aggregation:

```
?startkey=["201601"]&endkey=["201701"]&group_level=1 // find items in 2016, group by month
?startkey=["201601"]&endkey=["201701"]&group_level=2 // find items in 2016, grouped by month and product code
```

This could get you monthly totals of product sales, for example.

Comment: @ Glynn Thanks for the response, but what i want is to get the total number of products between two range of months and for that i have to put productid as first key and period as second key. If i reverse the keys element it will give me the count of productids for particular month. Hope i am able to explain my problem..